# Parser generator for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dsl, parser-generator

Can anyone recommend a parser generator that will produce win32 Delphi code? What I'm trying to do is create a simple Domain-Specific Language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How complex is your DSL?

I created a parser (in Delphi) for the new Delphi RIDL language to support some in-house COM generation tools we use.

My approach was to use ANTLR to play around with the syntax rules until I had something that parsed the various test files I had. I then hand-coded a recursive descent parser (based on the Java generated by ANTLR). I was also using the Castalia Delphi Parser in the project, so I based my lexical analyser on that.

Recursive descent parsers are actually really simple (but tedious :-) ) to write manually.

Comment: That's a good idea. My DSL is pretty simple. I like the idea of prototyping it in ANTLR too.

Comment: Lets assume it is SQL. How hard would this be?

Answer (score 5):

The Delphi versions of Coco/R are quite ok:

http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/

most notably Pat Terry's one:

http://www.scifac.ru.ac.za/coco/

Comment: Most Coco/R implementations for Delphi are very outdated. I updated DCocoR to work with Delphi XE2, the source is here: http://code.google.com/p/dcocor/

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde that was over 10 years ago. is it still going strong?

Comment: @theking2 Project has moved here: https://github.com/VilleKrumlinde/dcocor. I still use it in latest Delphi version. If you notice any problems with it then please create issue on the github page.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://www.grendelproject.nl/dyacclex/

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty old school though. Writing a DSL is already pushing the bounds of acceptability. lex/yacc would just cause people to panic. Regrettably I may have to do my DSL as an XML language.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this at all and I just noticed the information while I was reading through the documentation, but FastScript, in their documentation which you can get [here](http://www.fast-report.com/pbc_download/fs_en.pdf), says that you can use their parser to create your own language which you specify in an XML file.  This might give you something you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Antlr For Delphi 3.1.1](http://www.sqlitedeveloper.com/antlr-delphi-3-1).

> SharpPlus Antlr For Delphi Target
>   3.1.1, a language tool that provides a framework for constructing
>   recognizers, interpreters, compilers
>   with Delphi!

It is a commercial product. I have no idea what it is like.